# How to disable bluebooth mouse battery on Power Indicator

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth, indicator, battery

I use Ubuntu 14.04v on my HP ENVY 14 (14-k030TX)

Power Indicator contains my Bluetooth mouse's battery but it's wrong , and it will an average of the battery level on my Power Indicator, so the battery level display on Power Indicator is wrong.

How can I remove it from Power Indicator, I only want see my laptop's battery level?